# Preventing change in colour and background colour of selected option when blurred

Tags: html, css

This is my select box in focus:

[image]

And my select box while blurred:

[image]

As you can see, the selected option for my focused select box is highlighted blue, whereas for my blurred select box, the selected option is highlighted grey.

---

This is my HTML if anyone needs it:

```
<select size='9' id="functions_select">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option selected>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    outline: none;  
}
```

---

Is it possible to make it such that when blurred, the selected option for my select box will remain blue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I have a solution for you:**

```css
* {
    outline: none;  
}


option:checked {
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    background: #1e90ff repeat url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Istm3.jpg");
}
```

```html
<select size='9' id="functions_select" multiple>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option selected>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

It using `background-image` for `option`, this won't let browser use `default` background color.

Comment: Hmm that's a smart way to do it, but now when blurred, the text turns from white to black. Any way to fix that?

Comment: yeah, already working on it! trying to find a solution for it, I'll be back with update if I found.

Comment: As far as I know, `<options>` are styled by the browser theme (which is supposed to get those colors from the OS theme). The text color is called `-internal-inactive-list-box-selection-text`, but I don't think it's overridable. Nice trick with the image tho`. :)

Comment: @chris97ong found a solution for text, use `-webkit-text-fill-color: white;` I think it work on FF with `-moz-` too. Answer is updated.

Comment: @jiff Awesome! Thanks a lot! Will this work in all major browsers (if I use `-moz-` and all the other variations) ?

Comment: Your welcome, no I tested on FF without it, it works fine! have not Opera or etc but guess there is no need to use `prefix`s.